# invoke API gateway by its domain name

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway with custom domain names set up, it works fine if I visit the custom domain name but if I visit the API Gateway domain name (*https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com*) directly I just got:

> {"message":"Forbidden"}

My understanding is that custom domain name here is just like an alias to the original API Gateway domain name and is just a prettier name for it so I should be invoking the api gateway by either of them?[image]

Comment: what is the stage name, we must suffix the stage name with api gateway endpoint. if stage name is 'qa' then the url we need to try is `https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa` , when we use custom domain name, it will directly point to a stage that is defined in 'API mappings'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Gateway REST can be invoked in two different ways.

- Directly with execute api invoke URL suffixed by stage name.

Example: https://`ab11cde222`.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`dev` , where `ab11cde222` is api id and `dev` is stage name.

- Custom Domain: Adding a custom domain with in API Gateway and API mapping pointing to a particular stage and a route53 A record entry for hosted zone.

Since we can point the domain directly to a stage in api mappings, we don't have to suffix stage name when we use direct domain name.

[image]

There are many reasons why `{"message":"Forbidden"}` can occur as listed [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/), every reason either points to a call of an invalid/non-existent api or missing/invalid keys. Since the direct domain name is working fine, it seems like missing stage name suffix is most probable cause.

Comment: I have the path set to `test` and my "https://d-56789qwert.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/\${MAPPING_PATH}/\${API_METHOD}/" has "test" as MAPPING_PATH, but still I have "x-amzn-ErrorType" = "ForbiddenException". Cheked the link in your answer, 1. I dont have API Authorization(it's `NONE`); 2. I don't have WAF; 3. I have `x-apigw-api-id` in the response header; 4. The default endpoint is not disabled. I can't figure out what's happening.. My next work-around to try is firebase...